# Как будет быстрее.. через php или mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Добрый вечер, допустим имеем mysql таблицу с 10 000 записей, и.. нужно, скажем посчитать сумму всех этих записей, или среднее арифметическое, не суть. Какой вариант будет лучше: при запросе попросить mysql все посчитать и прислать нам результат или вытянуть всё в массив и потом уже в php сосчитать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете использовать функцию SUM MySQL

```
select SUM(столбец) from таблица;
```

Практически наверняка результат будет быстрее подсчета в PHP в силу встроенности решения.

Answer (score 1):

Через mysql, если конечно правильно составите запрос.

Comment: а правильно это как будет?
можно примерчик в двух словах или ссылочку?

Comment: Сумма `SUM()`,  
Среднее `AVG()` и т.д.  
Смотри [агрегатные функции][1].


  [1]: http://www.deepedit.ru/agregatnye-funktsii-gruppirovka-zapisey.html

Comment: все так как я и думаю) я если честно даже не знаю как иначе можно в mysql посчитать сумму записей, как ни функцией SUM()   :)

всем спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Я считаю SQL быстрее, да и хороший тон.
**mysql**, сразу получил запрос тут же обработал и вернул значение.
**php**, отправил запрос, получил ответ, обработал, вывел.